# Explore a matrix using Chebyshev distance

Tags: c++, c

What is the fastest way of exploring an array from a point (i,j) , using Chebysev distance?

My aproach:
I am currently defining 2 one dimensional arrays that store the directions for the start then compute with a For what is left when radius > 1 ( radius is the "radius" of the chebysev circle I wanna explore the array) . I am finding I am exploring some elements twice . Is there an algorithm that shows what is the best aproach ?

Be 0 the distance between (i,j) and himself . I would want the matrix to be explored like this ( the numbers represent the distance between i,j and them). Ofcourse i,j is not always it the middle , it must be any point I choose .

```
2 2 2 2 2  
2 1 1 1 2  
2 1 0 1 2  
2 1 1 1 2  
2 2 2 2 2
```

Thank you and excuse my english :)

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you mean by "explore"? What is the output you would like to receive? Do you want the set of all points that are within a certain Chebysev distance of a given point?

Comment: I edited to make it more clear :) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) algorithm. It is just a simple loop with a queue.
Your "edges" on are links between the position `(i, j)` and its 8 neighbors:

```
(i-1,j)
(i-1,j-1)
...
(i+1,j+1)
```